# Generate an internal URL in twig

Tags: 8, theming

I want to generate an internal URL in my twig template
Here is my code but it's not working

```
{% if(is_admin) %}
                    <li class="edit-sidebar-menu">
                        <a href="{{ url('admin/structure/menu/manage/fixed-sidebar-menu') }}">Edit Menu</a>
                    </li>
{% endif%}
```

Comment: instead of path please use route name in url().

Comment: Thanks but How I can get the route name of this URL

Comment: please check from .links.menu.yml.

Comment: but this URL for a custom menu created by me

Comment: then please check in your custom module have you created links.menu.yml / routing.yml? if not then first you need to define routing.yml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate an internal url in Twig you can follow these steps:

1. Install the module [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel).
2. Go to **Routes Info** (/devel/routes) and search in the browser for the path :

[image: Devel Routes Info]

3. Add the route name and the route parameter to `url()`:

`<a href="{{ url('entity.menu.edit_form', {'menu': 'fixed-sidebar-menu'}) }}">Edit Menu</a>`

Comment: Incase if you have a dynamic variable in plance of 'fixed-sidebar-menu' the would be like 
<a href="{{ url('entity.menu.edit_form', {'menu': variable }) }}">Edit Menu</a>

here the "varialbe" is a twig variable that renders the string, no need to put that in curly braces {{ }}

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed drupal console. Use the below command to list all routes in the site

```
drupal debug:router
```

Route name for admin/structure/menu/manage/{menu}  is

```
entity.menu.edit_form
```

So twig code should look like

```
<a href="{{ url('entity.menu.edit_form',{'menu':'fixed-sidebar-menu'}) }}">Edit Menu</a>
```

Comment: Very good, working fine, thanks so much, but if you don't have a Drupal console installed like me, you can use Devel module

Answer (score 0):

please try like this:

```
<a href="{{ url('contact.my_page') }}">{{ 'Contact'|t }}</a>
```

for more details look at this link: https://www.drupal.org/node/2486991#path

Comment: How I can get the route of this URL  "admin/structure/menu/manage/"

Comment: @Mohamed Osama Gbril Most of routes are configured by means of yml configuration files. You can find related routing file using `grep` tool as follows. `grep -r --include=*.routing.yml admin/structure/menu/manage`

Comment: Another approach is using Twig tweak module which has a function to build a URL from system path.